# memory use in docker exceed the xmx control or less than xms

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

in my docker file

```
JAVA_OPTS = "-server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/logs/dump"
```

```
 ps aux | grep 18657
root     18657 29.6  4.5 4865248 1477012 ?     Ssl  17:26  12:22 /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

the thread memory 1477012  is more than 1G
so my question is : 600m more memory are noheap memory and how can i find out what is using it
also when i set JAVA_OPTS = "-server -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/logs/dump"
when the docker container run and i find the java thread memory is less than 2g.
in my mind, xms is the start heap memory, java thread memmory using can not less the xms

Comment: That picture is not readable.  It looks like it's a screen shot of a terminal: can you delete the picture and replace it with the actual text content of the error message?

Comment: ok.i will replace it